# Permission Denied when specifying package.json scripts with sh -ac to point to specific .env (react)

Tags: reactjs, npm, environment-variables, sh, package.json

I just created a new react app using npx create-react-app, and added a few .env files (.env.staging, .env.development, .env.production)
I don't want to use dependencies like env-cmd and saw a few post about using the shell cmd to specify the .env file I want to target.

The package.json file script is as follow:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "sh -ac '. ./.env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts build'",
  "build:staging": "REACT_APP_ENV=staging npm run build",
  "build:production": "REACT_APP_ENV=production npm run build"
},
```

The .env.staging:

```
REACT_APP_CUSTOM_NODE_ENV = "staging"
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT = "https://boarding.staging.com"
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT_TITLE = "Staging Env"
```

When doing `>npm run build:staging` am getting the following error

`>npm run build:staging`

```
> env-vars@0.1.0 start:staging
> REACT_APP_ENV=staging npm run start
> env-vars@0.1.0 start
> sh -ac './ .env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts start'

sh: 1: ./: Permission denied
```

The app still runs but I'm unable to specify the needed .env.staging file for my variables.
Played around with running the sh -ac in the cmd line and still the same error.

```
 ✘ ~/env-vars >chmod +u+r+w+x ./.env.staging
 ✘ ~/env-vars >ls -la .env.staging
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 john john 132 Jan 19 20:38 .env.staging

 ✘ ~/env-vars > sh -ac './ .env.staging';
sh: 1: ./: Permission denied
```

I'm dont wan't to have to set permissions for each file as it seems wrong, but still if I try it I get same error. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Even tried with bash
`"staging": "bash -ac ./ ./.env.staging; react-scripts start"`

```
npm run staging

> playground@0.1.0 staging
> bash -ac ./ ./.env.staging; react-scripts start

./.env.staging: ./: Is a directory
```

And copying scripts from other articles I get Not Found!

```
"start-env": "sh -ac '. /home/geuxor/code/playground/playground/.env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts start'",
"start-dev": "REACT_APP_ENV=staging npm run start-env",
```

`npm run start-dev`

```
> playground@0.1.0 start-dev
> REACT_APP_ENV=staging npm run start-env
> playground@0.1.0 start-env
> sh -ac '. /home/geuxor/code/playground/playground/.env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts start'

sh: 1: /home/geuxor/code/playground/playground/.env.staging: REACT_APP_CUSTOM_NODE_ENV: not found
sh: 2: /home/geuxor/code/playground/playground/.env.staging: REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT: not found
sh: 3: /home/geuxor/code/playground/playground/.env.staging: REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT_TITLE: not found
```

- using WSL2 / React 17.0.2 / have not installed dotenv as its inbuild in react / zsh 4.8

Comment: i know you dont want to use any dependencies, however dotenv is great and easy to use. You could choose between files using `require('dotenv').config({ path: .env.staging })`

Comment: yes, I agree. But dotenv is already built in React which allows me to do process.env.X in my code. React also gives the ability to specify .env / .env.development / .env.production. The only limitation is that I don't see any other way than using sh cmd to work with custom environment variable files (.env.staging).

Comment: use the path variable to point directly to the .env.staging file

Comment: Thanks Keaton, it has stopped complaining now, but now the react app is unable to see any of the variables...
I tried different variants of the following without luck
   
`"staging": "sh -ac . /home/geuxor/code/playground/playground/.env.staging; react-scripts start",`

Comment: `require('dotenv').config({ path: ./home/geuxor/code/playground/playground/.env.staging })`

Comment: what happens if you try that? Just curious

Comment: Compiled with problems:
ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 24:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/geuxor/code/playground/env-vars/node_modules/dotenv/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 26:13-28
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 28:11-24

Answer (score 0):

Docker could work since you can specify env vars easily but it might not make sense to introduce it for your use case.
To solve your problem, you have to keep in mind some things:
Standard shells don’t understand the “dotenv” syntax by default, the common syntax to export env vars is this one, so you have to update your .env contents to look like this:
`export VAR1=value`
`export VAR2=value`
NPM scripts already run within a shell so there’s not need for you to wrap your command in sh -ac '…'
If you look closely, the command in the package.json you showed is different form the one that is being executed, I suspect maybe you made a typo? The error you’re getting is because you’re trying to execute the current directory (./) which will not work
Try this:

```
"build": "source ./.env.${REACT_APP_ENV} && react-scripts build",
"build:staging": "REACT_APP_ENV=staging npm run build",
"build:production": "REACT_APP_ENV=production npm run build",
```

Using source instead of . will make typos less likely, and the && will ensure the build doesn’t happen if sourcing variables fails for some reason.